# SalesForce UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Error trying to determine data category visibility for user

Tags: web-services, salesforce

We started to receive following error from SalesForce while there were no changes to our code.

Did anyone experience the same error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is Salesforce issue after Winter '15 Release Deployment. 
As i currently see, only sandbox instances are affected. 
Posted a case to support portal, waiting for reply.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem trying to execute any SOSL query.

For example:

```
system.debug([FIND 'John' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account (Id, Name), Contact, Opportunity, Lead]);
```